# Refactoring specific nested loops in c++

Tags: c++, lambda, nested-loops, c++17

I am working with a c++ framework (`ROOT`), that does not support directory advanced directory operations, so when I'm generating my (quite compex) directory system in a file, I usually end up using lots of ugly nested for loops. My question is, is it possible to replace a pattern like the one showed here with a less repetetive approach? Using something like lambdas that accept other lambdas as their arguments, or whatsoever (the linked code is just a small part of the dir system creation)?

```
// Disk
t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk_level_comparison");
gDirectory   -> mkdir(layerDirName);
for(std::size_t sideIndex = 0, maxSideIndex = sideNames.size(); sideIndex < maxSideIndex; ++sideIndex)
{
   const char* sideDirName = sideNames[sideIndex].c_str();
   t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk_level_comparison");
   gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
   gDirectory -> mkdir(sideDirName);
   gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
   for(std::size_t diskIndex = 0, diskMaxIndex = diskNames.size(); diskIndex < diskMaxIndex; ++diskIndex)
   {
      const char* diskDirName = diskNames[diskIndex].c_str();
      t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk_level_comparison");
      gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
      gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
      gDirectory -> mkdir(diskDirName);
   }
}
// Disk-ring
t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk-ring_level_comparison");
gDirectory   -> mkdir(layerDirName);
for(std::size_t sideIndex = 0, maxSideIndex = sideNames.size(); sideIndex < maxSideIndex; ++sideIndex)
{
   const char* sideDirName = sideNames[sideIndex].c_str();
   t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk-ring_level_comparison");
   gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
   gDirectory -> mkdir(sideDirName);
   gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
   for(std::size_t diskIndex = 0, diskMaxIndex = diskNames.size(); diskIndex < diskMaxIndex; ++diskIndex)
   {
      const char* diskDirName = diskNames[diskIndex].c_str();
      t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk-ring_level_comparison");
      gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
      gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
      gDirectory -> mkdir(diskDirName);
      gDirectory -> cd(diskDirName);
      for(std::size_t ringIndex = 0, ringMaxIndex = ringNames.size(); ringIndex < ringMaxIndex; ++ringIndex)
      {
         const char* ringDirName = ringNames[ringIndex].c_str();
         t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_disk-ring_level_comparison");
         gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
         gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
         gDirectory -> cd(diskDirName);
         gDirectory -> mkdir(ringDirName);
      }
   }
}
// Blade
t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_blade_level_comparison");
gDirectory   -> mkdir(layerDirName);
for(std::size_t sideIndex = 0, maxSideIndex = sideNames.size(); sideIndex < maxSideIndex; ++sideIndex)
{
   const char* sideDirName = sideNames[sideIndex].c_str();
   t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_blade_level_comparison");
   gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
   gDirectory -> mkdir(sideDirName);
   gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
   for(std::size_t diskIndex = 0, diskMaxIndex = diskNames.size(); diskIndex < diskMaxIndex; ++diskIndex)
   {
      const char* diskDirName = diskNames[diskIndex].c_str();
      t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_blade_level_comparison");
      gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
      gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
      gDirectory -> mkdir(diskDirName);
      gDirectory -> cd(diskDirName);
      for(std::size_t ringIndex = 0, ringMaxIndex = ringNames.size(); ringIndex < ringMaxIndex; ++ringIndex)
      {
         const char* ringDirName = ringNames[ringIndex].c_str();
         t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_blade_level_comparison");
         gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
         gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
         gDirectory -> cd(diskDirName);
         gDirectory -> mkdir(ringDirName);
         gDirectory -> cd(ringDirName);
         for(std::size_t bladeIndex = 0, bladeMaxIndex = bladeNames.size(); bladeIndex < bladeMaxIndex; ++bladeIndex)
         {
            const char* bladeDirName = bladeNames[bladeIndex].c_str();
            t_outputFile -> cd("ROC_efficiency_blade_level_comparison");
            gDirectory -> cd(layerDirName);
            gDirectory -> cd(sideDirName);
            gDirectory -> cd(diskDirName);
            gDirectory -> cd(ringDirName);
            gDirectory -> mkdir(bladeDirName);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

An easy-to-understand interpretation of what this does: it goes back to the root directory in a file, then creates many directories there, each of them containing the same subdirectory-system. The depth is different for the cases, and everytime a new subdirectory is created, the program has to go back to the root directory first.

**Example:**

```
├── FPix/
│   ├── Positive_Side
│   │   ├─ Disk_1
│   │   │   ├─ Ring_1
│   │   │   │   └─ Some_other_nested_levels
│   │   │   └─ Ring_2
│   │   │       └─ Some_other_nested_levels
│   │   ├─ Disk_2
│   │   │   ├─ Ring_1
│   │   │   │   └─ Some_other_nested_levels
│   │   │   └─ Ring_2
│   │   │      └─ Some_other_nested_levels
│   │   └─ ...
│   │       └─ Same_as_the_other_disks
│   │
│   └── Negative_side
│        └─ Same_as_the_positive_side
│
├── ROC_efficiency_disk_level_comparison
│   └─ The_nesting_here_only_goes_until_disks
│        └─ ...
│
├── ROC_efficiency_ring_level_comparison
│   └─ The_nesting_here_only_goes_until_rings
│        └─ ...
│
└── Many_many_other_directories_that_have_the_same_dirs_but_different_levels_of_nesting
```

Comment: could you define your Directory structure in a tree and then use a recursive approach to generate the actual folders? That might look slightly more pleasing

Comment: How would I go about that? Could it simplify the directory creation process?

Comment: I'd start with extracting "take path, break into parts, make all directories alongside it" into a separate function, then use it in loops.

Comment: Well, that is what the problem is, it requires lots of nesting and an ugly code. I'll add details of how my filesystem is planned to look.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the example structure you have posted as a tree, with the root directory as the root, the subfolders as nodes and the subdirectories of those directories as nodes of those nodes, etc (until you reach the end of your directory structure).
Then you could do something like

`def treedir(root):
    os.mkdir(root)
    for son in nodes:
        treedir(son)`

Which would generate the entire structure, assuming you correctly defined the tree.

Edit: I just realized I posted python code and you are using C++, but I am sure you get the general idea.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the creation of the directories, it is the definition of a tree, that has a highly repetitive pattern to it.

Comment: @AdamHunyadi Well, at SOME level you're obviously going to have to define your directory structure. Unless your directory structures can be derived from some basic ruleset, your only choice is to define the whole thing in some fashion, whether that is the directory-creating code itself, a datastructure like a tree, or a File you read from.